# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in HTMLElement

Tags: c#, html, browser

I am getting this error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

in the following line

```
 foreach (HtmlElement elementintable in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("level_0").All)
        {
            if (elementintable.TagName == "A")
            {
                //insert key and string to each node
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(elementintable.GetAttribute("href").Split('#')[1], elementintable.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

The error is in the first line..
`foreach (HtmlElement elementintable in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("level_0").All)`

Comment: I think...elementintable never get any value.

Comment: Debugging should show you what is null in about 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on the `foreach` line of code and hover over each part in Visual Studio and you can then see which bit is null and therefore causing the problem

Comment: In "webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("level_0") ", i am getting null value.

Comment: Have you definitely got an element in that `Document` called "level_0"? You should write your code to protect against that possibility anyway BTW (also helps with debugging)

Comment: Did this help you get to an answer?